# Calling javascript file from html file doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

Running this simple code where javascript line is placed under Script tags displays the desired alert message

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" >
alert('Hello World!');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to use an external .js file instead, I don't see it working at all. I tried surfing for solutions but nothing helped. I'm relatively new to scripting, so simple explanations are welcome. Thanks.

Html file placed at C:\UC

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../myTry.js" >
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

myTry.js placed inside C: has the following one line

```
alert('Hello World!');
```

I want this to work on IE 11

Comment: Should work fine. Look for errors in the developer console tab. You can see the developer option in any browser by pressing F12

Answer (score 0):

Change the path in `src="../myTry.js"`. Suppose you have saved `myTry.js` file in `c:\UC\myTry.js` mention the path as `<script type="text/javascript" src="c:\UC\myTry.js">`..
I tried it, it's working for me.

Comment: Just in case, put the javascript file in the same directory as your HTML file and modify as  `<script type="text/javascript" src="myTry.js">`

Comment: @sam100rav & Greenhorn Thank you very much for trying to help.

Actually the problem here with IE seems the below line I've added at the top to avoid script/active X pop up on IE. Removing this, external js link works fine.
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->

Note : I still have js and html files in the same locations as mentioned above.
       Also the above script has always worked fine on chrome as it doesn't show any pop up in first place.

Will come back with more questions.